# Communication between a .Net desktop application and a Silverlight application in browser

Tags: .net, silverlight, client-side-scripting, client-side-data

We have a .Net application running in a user's desktop and another Silverlight application running in a browser on the same desktop. I need to pass some data from the desktop .net application to the Silverlight client on the browser. Based on the data sent from the .Net app, Silverlight client needs to call a web service and display the result on the Silverlight client.
Can you please give me possible options to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible to host A WCF duplex service in your desktop application and you can communicate with the siverlight app, or You can use a proxy to send push notifications to silverlight check SignalR

Comment: I cannot use SignalR as the application that uses the Silverlight client is a proprietary application and I am not allowed to add the SingnalR server to the landscape. Instead, I am thinking of creating an ActiveX control that resides on the browser that runs the Silverlight app. Then my .net desktop app calls the ActiveX interface which raises ActiveX events. Add some Javascript coding to the Silverlight app to react to the ActiveX event on the client side. Will this work?

Comment: When I run the ActiveX within the browser, the desktop app has no way to get to the ActiveX methods. So I built an HTTP server that is started from ActiveX control and have the desktop communicate to the HTTP server via parameterised URL. This http server runs in the localhost. I can run the ActiveX and get the HTTP server to listen to calls from desktop app if activeX is loaded from a regular HTML file in browser. Now the problem is, Silverlight does not support HTTPListener. So I cannot start the HTTP server from ActiveX running in Silverlight application. Any alternative to this?